# Scala: for-comprehension for chain of operations

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I have a task to transform the following code-block:

```
  val instance = instanceFactory.create
  val result = instance.ackForResult
```

to for-comprehension expression.

As for-comprehension leans on enumeration of elements, I tried to get around it with wrapper class:

```
case class InstanceFactoryWrapper(value:InstanceFactory) {   
     def map(f: InstanceFactory => Instance): Instance
    = value.create()
 }
```

where map-method must handle only one element and return a single result:  Instance

I tested this approach with this expression:

```
 for {
     mediationApi <- InstanceFactoryWrapper(instanceFactoryWrapper)
}
```

But it does't work: IDEA recommends me to use foreach in this part. But "foreach" doesn't return anything, as opposed to map.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to change working code to a `for` comprehension just because?! - Anyways, what are the types of those expressions?

Comment: I consider it as a way to "chain" 2 code expressions: second expression consume the result of first. And, when 2-d complete without success, it may happen for a reason of malformed result of 1-t expression .

Comment: But you can just chain them like `instanceFactory.create.ackForResult`. There is no collection/async computation/error handling/other kind of producer that would justify `.map`. The only `.map`, `.flatMap` etc that I see possible in your original case is `type Id[A] = A` which doesn't make sense using directly in for-comprehension.

Comment: @Andrew how is your code different in that regard? Note that the purpose of `for` is to make monadic composition to look just like imperative code _(which si what you have)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put when working with List\Option\Either or other lang types comprehensions are useful to transform nested map\flatMap\withFilter into sequences.

#### Use custom classes in for-comprehension

But what about your own classes or other 3rd party ones?

You need to implement monadic operations in order to use them in for-comprehensions.
**The bare minimum: map and flatMap**.

Take the following example with a custom Config class:

```scala
case class Config[T](content: T) {

  def flatMap[S](f: T => Config[S]): Config[S] =
    f(content)

  def map[S](f: T => S): Config[S] =
    this.copy(content = f(content))
}

for {
  first  <- Config("..")
  _      =  println("Going through a test")
  second <- Config(first + "..")
  third  <- Config(second + "..")
} yield third
```

This is how you enable for-comprehension.